# How do I Plot Exponential Decay in Latex?

Tags: pgfplots, graphs

I am having trouble creating a graph that decays exponentially. I've gathered data for a project which shows a trend line of something like x^(-2.28+0.07x) but whenever I try to graph this function it graphs as a horizontal line. When I remove the negative symbol it is able to graph exponential growth, just not decay for some reason. Can someone show me an example for coding a graph that shows the exponential decay of the equation stated earlier in this question?

Here is the code that I have tried (unsuccessfully) thus far.

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
title={Coupling Strength in Coils as a Function of Distance},
xlabel={Distance (cm)},
ylabel={S12 Parameter (dB)},
xmin=3.5, xmax=10,
ymin=-80, ymax=80,
xtick={3.5,4,6,8,10},
ytick={0,-5,-10,-15,-20,-25,-30,-35,-40,-45},
legend pos=north west,
xmajorgrids=true,
ymajorgrids=true,
]

\addplot[
color=blue,]
    {x^(-2.28+0.07*x)};


\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Please show us what you've tried so far (minimal code example).

Comment: @TeXnician I've updated it. Is there some sort of package that may assist me here possibly?

Comment: You want different boundaries. Within x=4.5 to x=10 it is nearly a horizontal line, especially with those big y values (delete the boundary lines to see a first difference).

Comment: (i) calculate starting and end point of your function: you will see, that difference is very small (ii) rethink, what you like to show on your diagram. do you really need *y*-range between -80 an 80 (your function is between 0.1 and 0 ...).

Comment: @TKBC430, did one of the above tricks help to solve your problem or do you need further assistance?